# How to type a union of constants

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I would like to do the following:

```
from typing import Union, Literal
YES = 1
NO = 0
ValidResponse = Union[Literal[YES], Literal[NO]]
```

Of course, Python won't let me do this because `YES` and `NO` are considered to be variables, not literal numbers.

Obviously I can do `ValidResponse = Union[Literal[1], Literal[0]]`, but as a programmer editing this file later, it seems odd that in order to change what constant `YES` used (for example `YES = 'yes'`), I would need to change it in two different places.

**What's the best way to handle this scenario?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The `enum` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68812189/13990016) is often the cleaner solution in these situations, but note that it is *possible* to do this kind of thing with `typing.Literal`. You have to explicitly annotate your variables as being of a "literal" type. The `YesType` and `NoType` aliases that I've introduced aren't strictly necessary, but may be helpful for clarity:

```
from typing import Union, Literal

YesType = Literal[1]
NoType = Literal[0]

YES: YesType = 1
NO: NoType = 0

ValidResponse = Union[YesType, NoType]
```

Answer (score 5):

You should almost certainly just be using an `enum` instead:

```
import enum

class ValidResponse(enum.Enum):
    YES = 1
    NO = 0
```

Now you can use `ValidResponse` as an annotation:

```
def foo(response: ValidResponse) -> whatever:
    # do something with response
```